# Join two tables with multiple foreign keys

Tags: sql

Table `Trips`

```
TripId_PK
StartLocationId_FK
EndLocationId_FK
```

Table `Locations`

```
LocationId_PK
Name
```

How can I join the two table twice so that I can get a dataset like:

```
TripId_PK
StartLocationName
EndLocationName
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
SELECT  t.TripId_PK, ls.name StartLocationName, le.name EndLocationName
FROM    trips t
JOIN    locations ls
ON      ls.LocationId_PK = t.StartLocationId_FK
JOIN    locations le
ON      le.LocationId_PK = t.EndLocationId_FK
```

Answer (score 3):

You can try this

```
SELECT t.TripId_PK, ls.StartLocationName, le.EndLocationName
FROM Trips t
JOIN Locations ls ON t.StartLocationId_FK = ls.LocationId_PK
JOIN Locations le ON t.EndLocationId_FK = le.LocationId_PK
```